# Draw a circle with given curvature

Tags: math, drawing

I want to draw a circe with given curvature k.
I just need to know the y-coordinate for a given x-coordinate. So i.e. z = 1/k + sqrt(1/k^2 - x^2) is what I would normally use.
The problem is that my k is allowed to become zero. Which means that my circle becomes a line. For a mathematican thats no problem. But for my computer it is. For example when k is minimum double value, y will be infinity, for k == 0 I receive nan for y.
Are there any ways to get this done?

Comment: did you try checking if k = 0 before doing your computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gave the formula

```
y1 = 1/k + sqrt(1/k^2 - x^2)    // (1)
```

which describes the *upper half* of the circle with radius `1/k` and center `(0, 1/k)`. Now for small `k` these values become very large and will eventually be outside of your drawing are.

The *lower half* of the circle is given by

```
y2 = 1/k - sqrt(1/k^2 - x^2)    // (2)
```

For k approaching zero, these values "approach" the line `y = 0`. But for small values of `k`, (2) computes the difference of two large numbers. This causes a loss of precision and possible overflow.

But you can rewrite the formula (2) into the equivalent form

```
y2 = k * x^2 / (1 + sqrt(1 - k^2 * x^2))    // (2a)
```

Now you can compute the lower half of the circle  for small values of `k` and even for `k = 0` without any overflow or precision loss.

For the upper half you always have `y1 >= 1/k`. So if `1/k` is larger than the boundary of your drawing area, you can ignore the upper value. Otherwise you can compute `y1` via

```
y1 = 2/k - y2
```

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I wanted! I forgot a minus sign in my question (z = -1/k...) to have the line located on x-axis. Since I only need the upper half, I use your (2a) for it: `y = -k * x^2 / (1 + sqrt(1 - k^2 * x^2)) // (2b)`

Answer (score 2):

Given such border cases, I would just test the input parameters to see if one of them applies and use separate logic to just draw a horizontal or vertical line as appropriate if a border case applies.

That is a fairly common approach and computationally quite efficient.

When testing for border cases, test *k* to ensure that:
 - *k^2* will not overflow the data type in use
 - *k* is not so small that *1/k^2* will underflow the data type in use

In either case, use the appropriate border case logic.  Thanks @Godeke for pointing that out.

Comment: An important clarification is that your border case tests should not be of the form `k == 0` but instead of the form `k < minimum` where `minimum` would be a value for which the computation doesn't underflow for the precision used.

Comment: @Godeke: That's an important point.  I'll update the body of the answer to reflect that.